# Magento Custom Controller working on local, throwing 500 error on staging server

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am having quite a strange problem. I have just pushed my local build to our staging server. I have a custom module with custom controllers which, when accessed locally, work perfectly fine. However, when I attempt to access ONE SPECIFIC controller on staging, it throws a 500 server error. All of the other controllers I wrote work except for this custom IndexController.php I wrote. Again, everything works 100% on my local build. I have triple checked all of my .htaccess files, but maybe I’m missing something.

The strangest part of all of this is that it was working on staging two days ago! I have no idea what is causing this.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might go about troubleshooting this? Or, by chance, a solution?

Comment: If it's throwing a 500 server error that means the error's being logged in your webserver logs.  Find the log file, trigger the error, and look for the message that got loged.  (Also, if your dev machine is a mac, check your wordCasIng.  PHP's class names aren't case sensitive, but the file names they're autoloaded from are. )

Comment: I checked the staging server's log and all I am able to see is the following:
`<ipaddress> - - [13/Jun/2013:15:12:35 -0400] "GET /mrshirt/index/list HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: What is this controller good for? Maybe you are hitting the max execution time or memory is used up.

Comment: All it does is load a simple block with a small amount of content.
`$this->loadLayout();`
`echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('shirt/list')->setTemplate('shirt/list.phtml')->toHtml();`

Answer (score 3):

1: Clear your cache AND sessions .

2: Check if your module is installed using the free/open-source Module List Module

3 Drop some debugging code in the following method. The var_dumps will tell you which files/classes Magento's routers are looking for with your module, but can't find.

```
File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php

protected function _validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller)
{
$controllerFileName = $this->getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller);
if (!$this->validateControllerFileName($controllerFileName)) {
    var_dump($controllerFileName);
    return false;
}

$controllerClassName = $this->getControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
if (!$controllerClassName) {
    var_dump($controllerFileName);
    return false;
}

// include controller file if needed
if (!$this->_includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)) {
    var_dump($controllerFileName);
    return false;
}

return $controllerClassName;
}
```